# NJS-069: node-oracledb 6.0.3 requires Node.js 14.6 or later

Tags: node.js, cypress, node-oracledb

I'm trying to run Cypress, but find the following error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Cou.png)

I need to do oracle db connection for sql testing and tried many things to solve this problem.
If helps, here is my package.json file:
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swGFB.png)

I tried reinstalling node_modules and using nvm to switch node version.

Comment: Remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask). Quoting from it directly (including bold and all caps): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** — copy or type the text into the question._". Also, the error seems perfectly clear: your Node version is too old. In fact, version 14 isn't even supported anymore, the current LTS versions of Node are v16 (which will be EOL coming September) and v18, with the current version being v20

Comment: Your screenshot is for node-oracledb 5.5 but your question subject mentions 6.0.3.  Can you update your question with a consistent set of steps that you took?

Comment: With NVM I've switched version to 16.20.1, but still doesn't work.

Comment: The subject is the exact message displayed in VS Code terminal.

Comment: I've found this, but didn't understand how to apply on my cypress project: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1323